GoogleOAuthProvider isn't passing nonce, inline styles can't be applied
I have a react app which needs to use google oauth. Here's how I setup the root renderer:
import React from 'react';
import { GoogleOAuthProvider } from '@react-oauth/google';
import App from './pages/App';
import { createRoot } from 'react-dom/client';
import { BrowserRouter } from 'react-router-dom';

import "./index.css"

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
const root = createRoot(rootElement!);
const url = import.meta.env.VITE_REACT_APP_OAUTH_CLIENT_ID;

root.render(
  <BrowserRouter>
    <GoogleOAuthProvider clientId= {url} nonce={"F04DAE83-E065-4AB5-904F-C2E5E3B3390C"}>
      <React.StrictMode>
        <App />
      </React.StrictMode>
    </GoogleOAuthProvider>
  </BrowserRouter>
);


Supposedly, the nonce I pass to GoogleOAuthProvider will be passed along to the script it downloads so that things like setting an inline style will be allowed with appropriet content security policies.
GoogleOAuthProvider, to my understanding, loads a script from https://accounts.google.com/gsi/client which should add the nonce. However, when I load my app (which is behind a firewall so I can't provide a link sadly), I see a content security policy violation:
Refused to apply inline style because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: 
"style-src 'self' 'sha256-47DEQpj8HBSa+/TImW+5JCeuQeRkm5NMpJWZG3hSuFU=' 'sha256-mmA4m52ZWPKWAzDvKQbF7Qhx9VHCZ2pcEdC0f9Xn/Po=' 'sha256-6EhLFF8G95u/ybGSFfUDwCI+tUnGaFOU7YO6RWksdT8=' 'sha256-/VVOq+Ws/EiUxf2CU6tsqsHdOWqBgHSgwBPqCTjYD3U=' 'sha256-VFkcZKIwYxNm8Z6oY+AC70f2fuyHVm5fJgnpOkYBF3Q=' 'sha256-g9aHNH7iF2hhGZYtVVd5mKQSnyLPmXWw5gwiuxBVonI=' 'sha256-VjKqXV9i0mo5RzxvaQpz7qQA91PkjLVqLQGYNI4Cc/I=' 'sha256-NsEzkM762veirpWZeMiqlWTPdCYrm1uJHLzzwfYnDLM=' *.websitepolicies.io *.acom.ucar.edu orgnav.ucar.edu fonts.gstatic.com code.jquery.com *.googleapis.com angularjs.org angular-ui.github.io maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com www2.ucar.edu cdnjs.cloudflare.com netdna.bootstrapcdn.com  getbootstrap.com accounts.google.com nonce-F04DAE83-E065-4AB5-904F-C2E5E3B3390C". 
Either the 'unsafe-inline' keyword, a hash ('sha256-lmto2U1o7YINyHPg9TOCjIt+o5pSFNU/T2oLxDPF+uw='), or a nonce ('nonce-...') is required to enable inline execution.

As you can see, the nonce is included in the style-src of the Content-Security-Policy.
My best guess is that GoogleOAuthProvider isn't passing along the nonce but I don't see how I've set the nonce in the code is incorrect.
What am I missing here?
Lastly, I'm aware that a nonce should be generated everytime, but I will worry about proper generation of the nonce after I get it to work just once.
